# Is there an Ubuntu shortcut for moving the cursor to the next word

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I want something similar to Windows' Ctrl+Left/Right arrow key.

The effect is that the cursor moves to the beginning of the previous/next word.

I did not find anything on the Ubuntu documentation.

Any help?

Comment: Are you referring to graphical programs or the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most GUI programs, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> will work as expected. In the terminal, the defaults are different. You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> or you can set up your terminal to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> as well.

To do so, add these lines to your `~/.inputrc` file (create the file if it does not exist):

```
"\e[1;5D": backward-word ## good: Ctrl+left
"\eOd": backward-word
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\eOc": forward-word
```

Then, open a new terminal and the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>  shortcuts should work. For more info on the strange syntax used, see my answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/528538/151431).

Note, however, that this should be enabled by default on Ubuntu, at least it is on my 14.04 install.

Comment: @IoannisSouldatos parakalw.